# SDK 1.2.1 Windows: bees run logging library error (commons-logging-1.0.4.jar)

Tags: cloudbees

Our Setup:
Windows 7 CloudBees SDK 1.2.1 (and early versions)
Deploying ColdFusion 9 apps locally and at CloudBees

We find the following happens consistently:

Using the "bees run" command to deploy our app locally we ALWAYS receive a Java error having to do with "logging".  We have found that we can work around this by disabling the /lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar by renaming it as DISABLED.  The "bees run" command will now work and we can proceed normally.

However, when we use the "bees deploy" command we find that we must re-enable commons-logging-1.0.4.jar by naming it back to its original name.  As you might expect, this constant file renaming is not a true solution.

Can anybody help with this?

Here is the error (or part of it anyway)
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Lj
ava.lang.Class;@2d388e5e for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category) (Caused
 by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@2d388e5e for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.
Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category))

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classloading issue with commons-logging (that is also used by tomcat runtime as you invoke "bees run"). I suggest you include commons-logging-api.jar in your war as replacement for the full commons-logging library.